# Future get() returns void for int returning member function

Tags: c++11

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    int run(int a, const std::string& s)
    {
        std::cout << "a=" << a << ",s=" << s << std::endl;
        return a+1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto f = std::bind(&A::run,&a,5,std::placeholders::_1);
    std::packaged_task<int(const std::string&)> pt(std::move(f));

    auto fut = std::async(std::move(pt),"test");
    /// std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl; Does not compile
    fut.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Why fut.get() is returning void ? A::run is defined to return int and hence it should return int instead of void.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `packaged_task` instance to `async`, so return type for `future` is deduced based on:

```
std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>::operator()
void operator()( ArgTypes... args );
```

where `void` is returned.

If you want to get a result stored by `packaged_task`, you should read value stored by future returned by `packaged_task::get_future`:

```
A a;
auto f = std::bind(&A::run,&a,5,std::placeholders::_1);
std::packaged_task<int(const std::string&)> pt{std::move(f)};
std::future<int> fut = pt.get_future();
auto fut2 = std::async(std::move(pt),"test");
fut2.wait();   // wait until async's task is completed -> packaged_task was executed
std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl; // get result of packaged_task
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x3M111)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but still unclear why this decay of return type ?

Comment: `async` takes packaged task as argument. `future<RET>` will have as `RET` return type of passed callable object into async - in your case it is return type of `operator()` of packaged task, which is `void`. No decay on return type happens here. `async` just puts `void` into its future based on ` // -> void // <- packaged_task::operator()(...)` signature.